# MemoryError in 64-bit Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, out-of-memory

I'm running 64-bit Python 3 on Linux, and I have a code that generates lists with about 20,000 elements. A memory error occurred when my code tried to write a list of ~20,000 2D arrays to a binary file via the `pickle` module, but it generated all of these arrays and appended them to this list without a problem. I know this must take up a lot of memory, but the machine I'm using has about 100GB available (from the command `free -m`). The line with the error:

```
with open('all_data.data', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
>>> MemoryError
```

where `data` is my list of ~20,000 numpy arrays. Also, previously I was trying to run this code with about 55,000 elements, but while it was 40% of the way through with appending all the arrays to the `data` list, it just output `Killed` by itself. So now I'm trying to break it into segments, but this time I get a MemoryError. How can I bypass this? I was also informed that I have access to multiple CPUs, but I have no idea how to take advantage of these (I don't yet understand `multiprocessing`).

Comment: The memory it is referring to isn't storage memory but RAM. Have you tried writing the elements with smaller segments? Do so by opening the file in append ('a') instead of write

Comment: Also, writing on the same file with multiple processes would probably make you lose your element's order. The same file cannot be accessed by more processes simultaneusly in write mode

Comment: How can I see how much RAM I have access to? When I google this, I come across `free -m` which is what I have used, so I'm not sure what the difference is. Yes, if I break it up into even smaller segments then I was planning on renaming the file and just reading them all in in a separate code at the end. But I'm not sure if this would solve my problem, since I would probably just get another memory error, but unfortunately in the end I will need to operate on all 55,000 2D arrays in the same code.

Comment: Please provide more data in your question, what do these arrays contain? Provide full code sample if you can, so that we can try to re-create the error

Comment: The 2D arrays are data that come from various FITS files and have shape (790, 790) or so (not all of them have the same shape though), so unfortunately I cannot post all the actual data.

Comment: "free -m" tells you the correct amount of RAM - unless you are paying for a super-expensive server on the cloud, it is unlikely you have 100GB of it available, though. Use `free -mh` to have the command add the proper sufices (MB, GB) for you.

Comment: anyway, with my answer bellow you are unlikley to further experience memory errors, unless a single of these arrays is already too big, _and_ you are close to the total amount of RAM you have before starting to pickle.

Comment: I just did, and it is indeed 100 GB (I'm using a large server at work), although currently it's at 88 GB available as I'm running my code on a list of only 500 2D arrays.

Comment: yes - you have a lot of RAM, but the data is big - 20.000 800x800 arrays of 64bit floats would use 100GB by themselves. Pickling it at once would require roughly 100GB extra.

Comment: So if I only have the 100 GB available, and I pickle the arrays in one by one as demonstrated in your answer, won't I still run into a memory error when I later do operations with these arrays (if this whole file would use the whole 100GB)? Perhaps I need to divide into even smaller subsections at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickle will try to parse all your data, and likely convert it to intermediate states before writing everything to disk - so if you are using about half your available memory, it will blow up.

Since your data is already on a list, an easy workaround there is to pickle each array, and store it, instead of trying to serialize the 20000 arrays in a single go:

```
with open('all_data.data', 'wb') as f:
    for item in data:
        pickle.dump(item, f)
```

Then, to read it back, just keep unpickling objects from your file and appending then to a list, until the file is exhausted:

```
data = []
with open('all_data.data', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            data.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

This works because unpicking from a file is quite well behaved: the file pointer stays exactly at the point a pickled object stored in the file ends - further reads therefore start at the beginning of the next object.

Comment: Thank you. Will this preserve the order of my elements? Also, why is the `while True` line necessary here?

Comment: Yes, order is preserved. The `while True`  is needed to keep reading objects from the file - since the `with` statement does not repeat its block, it just provides a scope within which the file is open.  The stop condition for the while is the `EOFError` which will trigger a  `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use joblib

```
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).